# How can i handle out of scope problem in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

**HELLOO EVERYONE!!QUESTION BELOW, NEED YOUR HELP**

using CP;

int nbPilots = 50;

int nbLocations = 7;

int nbDays = 30;

range pilots = 1..nbPilots;

range days = 1..nbDays;

range locations = 1..nbLocations;

dvar boolean assign [pilots][days][locations] ;

dvar boolean rest [pilots][days][locations];

maximize sum(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)assign[i][j][l];

subject to{

forall(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)(assign[i][j][l]+assign[i][j+1][l]+assign[i][j+2][l]+assign[i][j+3][l]+assign[i][j+4][l]+assign[i][j+5][l]+assign[i][j+6][l]+rest[i][j+7][l]+rest[i][j+8][l] == 9); }

**how can i handle that [j+8] is also in days <=30**

Answer (score 0):

```
using CP;
int nbPilots = 50; 
int nbLocations = 7; 
int nbDays = 30;

range pilots = 1..nbPilots; range days = 1..nbDays; range locations = 1..nbLocations;

//decision variable/ 

dvar boolean assign [pilots][days][locations] ; dvar boolean rest [pilots][days][locations];

//objective/ 

minimize sum(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations)assign[i][j][l];

//constraints/
 subject to{


forall(i in pilots, j in days, l in locations:(j+8) in days)
  (assign[i][j][l]+assign[i][j+1][l]+assign[i][j+2][l]+assign[i][j+3][l]+
  assign[i][j+4][l]+assign[i][j+5][l]+assign[i][j+6][l]+rest[i][j+7][l]+rest[i][j+8][l] == 9);



}
```

works fine